# Moving active menu item onscreen for mobile

Tags: menus, mobile

I've created custom CSS to change my wordpress menu into a horizontal scroll for everything under 1057px. I've researched for hours on how to scroll the menu item onto the screen when selected. Any ideas? I've tried scrollintoview() but I'm unable to get this to work. Here is a link to the page: https://cqlcorpstaging.wpengine.com/our-services/custom-development/ Thanks!